# Change event not firing on textbox when data is changed through other code

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I need a change event to fire on an element without regard of how the element value was changed.

My use case here is that I need to change elements on a form whenever a particular textbox changes value.  The problem is that the element is populated by another button (a calendar button that lets the user choose a date which is then inserted in the first textbox).

Using the sample below, I need to know when "date1" changes so I can update "date2".  **I won't know the ID of the button--its dynamically generated by another tool--so I can't attach anything to that.**

I have the following HTML:

```
 <input type="text" id="date1" value="" />
 <input type="button" id="but1" value="click me" />
 <br/>
 <input type="text" id="date2" value="" />
```

And this JavaScript:

```
 $(function () {

     $("#but1").click(function () {
         $("#date1").val(new Date().toLocaleDateString());
     });

     $("#date1").change(function () {
         var d = new Date($("#date1").val());
         $("#date2").val(d.addDays(7));
     });

 });

 Date.prototype.addDays = function (days) {
     var current = this;
     current.setDate(current.getDate() + days);
     return current;
 };
```

Here is a jsfiddle I was using: http://jsfiddle.net/mYWJS/7/

**Update**: I added a DIV wrapper to the jsfiddle example in hopes that might inspire another solution.  I couldn't find a way to utilize it myself but my JavaScript skills are rather mediocre.

In regards to Fabricio's comment about DOM mutations, is there a DOM mutation solution that is somewhat browser independent?  There is no way for me to predict with certainty the browser that will be used here. I'm not too concerned about IE6, but the few solutions I've seen for DOM mutations seem to focus on Chrome.

Comment: `change` only fires for text inputs when the input loses focus after having its value changed after gaining focus. No focus = no change event. You can trigger a synthetic `.change()` event after changing it from your JS, but if you really need to watch over an input's value, you will need a DOM Mutation Observer which is mostly a hack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fire the event

```
$(function () {

    $("#but1").click(function () {
        $("#date1").val(new Date().toLocaleDateString()).change();
    });

    $("#date1").change(function () {
        var d = new Date($("#date1").val());
        $("#date2").val(d.addDays(7));
    });

});

Date.prototype.addDays = function (days) {
    var current = this;
    current.setDate(current.getDate() + days);
    return current;
};
```

Aleternate:

```
$("#date1").val(new Date().toLocaleDateString()).trigger('change');
```

EDIT: Given your clarification:

```
$(function () {
    $("#date1").next('input[type=button]').on('click',function () {
        $("#date1").val(new Date().toLocaleDateString()).change();
    });

    $("#date1").change(function () {
        var d = new Date($("#date1").val());
        $("#date2").val(d.addDays(7));
    });
});

Date.prototype.addDays = function (days) {
    var current = this;
    current.setDate(current.getDate() + days);
    return current;
};
```

NOTE: This example has them in the same table cell. If it is in a subsequent table cell use:

```
 $("#date1").next('td input[type=button]')
```

Comment: While this works it ignores the point I mentioned in my question that I don't really have access to the button. I won't know its name or ID.  I need a solution that just looks at the text box.

Comment: SO, to clarify, you don't know the id of `but1` input button? and if that is correct, do you know the id of its wrapper/containing element?

Comment: Its in a table cell which I can determine.  I also know its immediately preceded by the 'date1' textbox.

Comment: In future questions, help us help you by providing full contextual markup and really clear explanation of your challenge.

Comment: You're right, but sometimes its hard to foresee what info is valuable to get an answer.  I could probably provide a couple thousand lines of code to clearly define the issue, but I focused on what I felt I *really* needed... a way to always detect when the contents of a textbox changed.

Comment: You provide a fine workaround, but ultimately doesn't help me and that's clearly my fault.  I'll mark this as the answer because it will probably help somebody else.