# Best way to detect field value change that was caused by chrome content script

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension, content-script

I am writing a chrome plugin that makes use of a website (which I am also writing myself) to interact with the user.

A content script in the plugin changes certain field values in the website using jQueries `.val()` method.

The website needs to be able to detect such a change via its own javascript in order to update other stuff accordingly.

However, the value change [does not fire a onchange event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15421638/change-event-not-firing-on-textbox-when-data-is-changed-through-other-code) and since the website js and the content script are independent, the `element.change()` function in the websites jQuery does not  react when the event is fired from code in the content script.

What is the best way to make the website js detect a change in the value of the field?

PS: In case you consider this a design problem (communication between extension and website is mixed with display functionality) I would also be interested in your suggestion.

Comment: You are going to need to add an event listener to the element and watch for either onblur or onkeypress events.

Comment: Are you sure about that? Since content change is not initiated by the user, but by jQuery's `.val()`, I doubt that an `onblur` or `onkeypress` event is fired.

Comment: How about hidden input? Your extension can fill in that hidden input pointing where changes has been made, and website script can listen to the input `on.change` event. This certainly requires modification to the website though.

Comment: The core problem I was trying to formulate in the question is that there is no change event fired. At least I think so because jQueries `.change()` does not respond. See also here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15421638/change-event-not-firing-on-textbox-when-data-is-changed-through-other-code

Answer (score 0):

This is how I finally solved it:

```
inputChanged = function(inputElement,callback){

    oldInput = inputElement.val();

    setInterval(function(){
    if (oldInput!=inputElement.val()){
        oldInput = inputElement.val();
            callback();
    }
},200);
```

}

It's not elegant, but it works.